# Joomla 1.5 com_user and importing user plugins like Joomla 1.6 and above

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

When accessing com_users component in Joomla 1.6 and 1.7 on front-end the application automatically imports all plugins from 'user' group. Obviously it is very useful if one doesn't want to create a component to simply pass some variables to a plugin.

Ok. let's make it simplier:

1. User gets an activation link: http://example.com/index.php?option=com_users&task=edit&emailactivation=1&u=63&d077b8106=1 and clicks it.
2. Of course the component will omit **emailactivation** and other params simply displying "Edit Profile Form" (or login form for guests).
3. Then JApplication imports all plugins from '**user**' group, which triggers __constructors

Basically, with plugin's **__constructor** one can set up simple action like this one below:

```
class plgUserAccountactivation extends JPlugin
{
    public function __construct(& $subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $config);

        if(isset($_GET['emailactivation'])) {
            // check token
            // activate account, email or whatever
            // redirect with message
        }
    }
}
```

Wow! It works, it is not necessary to create a whole controller to handle one simple task.

But hold on a minute...

- In the link change index.php?option=com_users to index.php?option=com_user
- And let's try on Joomla 1.5...

Hey, hey, nothing happens com_user didn't import anything at all and __constructor wan't called.

I am very troubled by this in Joomla 1.5 and I don't feel like writing whole component.

Should anybody have some bright idea, please let me know.

**Edit:**
I've solved my problem by sending the link in the following form:

> http:/example.com/index.php?option=com_user&**task=logout**&emailactivation=1&u=63&d077b8106=1

This way user plugins are included and __constructors are executed. But this is so frivolous as **task=logout** doesn't really encourage to click in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with 1.5 is, that events are more limited. You have the following events available: [Joomla 1.5 Plugin Events - User](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_events/User). I guess therefore your plugin is not initiated.

How about making this a system plugin and checking for the activation in the URL/request properties? Something like:

```
class plgSystemUseractiavation extends JPlugin {

  function onAfterInitialise(){

    $u = &JURI::getInstance(); 
    $option = trim(strtolower($u->getVar('option')));
    $emailactivation = trim(strtolower($u->getVar('emailactivation')));

    if( strlen($option  < 1) ){ // for SEF...
        $option = trim(strtolower(JRequest::getString('option')));
    }

    $app =& JFactory::getApplication(); 
    $appName = trim(strtolower($app->getName()));
    if( $appName === 'site' ){
        if( ( $option === 'com_users' ) || ( $option === 'com_user' ) ){
            if( $emailactivation === '1' ){
                // check token
                // activate account, email or whatever
                // redirect with message                        
            }
        }       
    }       
 }      
}
```

Comment: I need it as user plugin, besides your code would be executed on all sub-pages even in "com_content"

Comment: actually I've solve my problem temporary, see updated question

Comment: Yes, the plugin is always executed. But the computational effort is not much as it throughly checks whether it is in the right place and, for example in "com_content" immediately returns from the execution.